# I am getting an error while running kubectl version although I installed it by following the documention

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl

kubectl version
/home/lenovo/.local/bin/kubectl: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<' /home/lenovo/.local/bin/kubectl: line 1:` `NoSuchKey`The specified key does not exist.No such object: kubernetes-release/release//bin/linux/amd64/kubectl'

Comment: That sounds like the `kubectl` you have isn't actually the Kubernetes client binary.  Did you get it through a `curl` command or a similar download?  Was that actually successful?

Comment: What's your OS ?

Comment: my os is ubuntu

Comment: Did you tried other commands like get pods or describe something ?

Comment: Now the problem is solved i re-install it... but now another problem come which is   ----The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?--- after running kubectl get pod

Answer (score 2):

I cleared kubectl from `/usr/local/bin`

and also from `/home/$USER/.local/bin`

And run the commands below:

```bash
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.24.7/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"

curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/v1.24.7/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl.sha256"

echo "$(cat kubectl.sha256)  kubectl" | sha256sum --check

sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /home/$USER/.local/bin/kubectl
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).